# installed tar video down loader in Ubuntu

Tags: youtube

Installed TAR and front end for youtube downloader ok on launching the program  how do I add the videos?.In windows I have a down loader that is automatic in adding the video when played.Where do I go from there please

Comment: In Windows you probably used a browser extension that automatically identified the video file to download. You should look for similar extension for browser you are using in Ubuntu (probably Firefox). Go to Addons in Firefox menu, then click "More Addons" at the bottom and you can search for addons to install. I see that it suggests "Video Download Helper" right on the first page...

Comment: Great I`m progressing at the stage where downloader helper is installed and when I open it I have the option to download the video but where does it go to unable to find? Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know as I haven't used the extension, but try your "Downloads" or "Videos" folder...